# How to dismiss the current ViewController and go to another View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I am new to Swift and I want to know how to dismiss the current view controller and go to another view.

My storyboard is like the following: MainMenuView -> GameViewController -> GameOverView. I want to dismiss the GameViewController to go to the GameOverView, not to the MainMenuView.

I use the following code in my MainMenuView:

```
@IBAction func StartButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as! GameViewController
    self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    restGame()
}
```

In the GameViewController, I use this code, but it doesn't dismiss the GameViewController.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverView") as! GameOverView
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

This is My GameOverView Code :

```
class GameOverView: UIViewController{
    // save the presenting ViewController
    var presentingViewController :UIViewController! = self.presentViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func ReplayButton(sender: UIButton) {
        restGame()
        didPressClose()
    }
    @IBAction func ReturnMainMenu(sender: UIButton) {
        Data.GameStarted = 1
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) {
            // go back to MainMenuView as the eyes of the user
            self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
        }
       /* let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScene") as! MainScene
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)*/

    }
    func restGame(){
        Data.score = 0
        Data.GameHolder = 3
        Data.GameStarted = 1
        Data.PlayerLife = 3.0
        Data.BonusHolder = 30
        Data.BonusTimer = 0
    }
    func didPressClose()
    {
        self.self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
    }
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    deinit{
        print("GameOverView is being deInitialized.");

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you can do is let the `GameOverView` be presented, after all when you presenting it the `GameViewController` is below in the hierarchy, and then in your `GameOverView` run the following code to close both when you want to dismiss the `GameOverView`, like in the following way:

```
@IBAction func ReturnMainMenu(sender: UIButton) {
    // save the presenting ViewController
    var presentingViewController: UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) {
          // go back to MainMenuView as the eyes of the user
          presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The above code need to be called when you want to dismiss the `GameOverView`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: it doesn't work it give an error "Getter for 'presentingViewController' with Objective-C selector 'presentingViewController' conflicts with getter for 'presentingViewController' from superclass 'UIViewController' with the same Objective-C selector" i updated my post so you can see my code for GameOverView

Comment: First of all, `var presentingViewController :UIViewController! = self.presentViewController` outside a function doesn't work , you need to declare it and then inside your `viewDidLoad` instantiate it. Your problem is regarding that when you declare `presentingViewController` as a stored property the `UIViewController` make conflict with his own `presentingViewController`, solution: change the name. The above code is for be called inside a function to avoid this kind of conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the help it return to MainMenu but the GameViewController isn't dismiss yet the memory wasn't released

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't dismiss yet the memory wasn't released"?

Comment: When i dismiss from GameViewController the memory decrease from 60MB to 40MB but if i dismiss from GameOverView the memory stay at 60MB and if i play again the game the memory increase from 60 to 100 MB

Comment: Then I recommend you  to use Instruments and find where is the bug memory.

Comment: It work find now thanks but is it normal that every time i start the game this error is prompt "<CAMetalLayer: 0x14cdf9cb0>: calling -display has no effect." i don't use CAMetalLayer in my code how do i solve it thx

Answer (score 3):

The below code will take you to the main VC, Here's a tried and tested piece of code.

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```